# How to Fix images and video Not Showing Up in Safari?

Tags: wordpress, safari, cross-browser

I am working on wordpress site.Where on every browser my site works fine.But on safari browser sometimes images and video won't load it only shows black screen.

Comment: What do you see in the developer tools' console or network tabs? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

If you are using any plugin you should check with plugin code and check with the plugin development forum regarding the same issue.

or

It may be the browser compatability issue for safari

Try this please

```
Go to /Library/Internet Plugins folder and delete WacomSafari.plugin.
```

for Referrence:[Click here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/video-display-firefox-safari-chrome.html)

Comment: Are you using any wordpress plugin for video?

Comment: no but I am using w3 total cache plugin..And site data is huge and site is on cloud..

Comment: Okay for the video to work in Safari you have to have Quicktime installed on your machine. Try to install quicktime in two machine and check whether the video playing in both machine.  And if it worked out then you should go with automatic embedded-quicktime in wordpress

Comment: suggestion : To check just copy that URL of the images in wordpress website and paste it safari browser.  please do this and let me know

Comment: I have checked it on browser but sometimes site loads properly but sometimes only show empty div instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

Safari: Preferences: Advanced: Internet plug-ins: Stop plug-ins to save power: unselect

Worked for me on Safari 9.1